# Elasticsearch: Paginating a stream of results

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, stream

## My settings

[image]

Consider a stream of logs continuously sent to an [Elasticsearch cluster](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) using [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat).

## My problem

I would like to continuously read the stream of logs from Elasticsearch. Needless to say, ES does not feature a streaming API, so I have to paginate using consecutive HTTP calls.

## What have I tried

- Using [`from` / `size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html)
- Using [Search After](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html)

## Query body for reference

```
{
  "size": 5,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "source:*.log",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": {
      "include": ["message", "@timestamp"],
      "exclude": "_*"
  }
}
```

## My question

**How can I paginate a stream of log entries from Elasticsearch?**

Comment: Did you find the solution ?)