# Elasticsearch: Fetching the last N records from an index

Tags: elasticsearch, tail

## My problem

I am using Elasticsearch to store a stream of log lines sent from Filebeat. I would like to implement a `tail`-like functionality, which fetches the latest N log lines - by their timestamp - from a given index.

## What have I tried

Using a combination of `"from": 0` and sorting in descending order on `@timestamp`.

### `query.json`:

```
{
  "size": 5,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "source:*.log",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": {
      "include": ["message", "@timestamp"],
      "exclude": "_*"
  }
}
```

## Broader Context & Design

For the complete design, see [Elasticsearch: Paginating a stream of results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632895/elasticsearch-paginating-a-stream-of-results).

## My question

How do I fetch the latest

Comment: Your query is pulling the most recent 5 documents.  What's not working?

Comment: Seems to be a Filebeat issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Filebeat issue, not an ES issue.

My logs are unstructured, meaning that they do not contain an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) sortable date prefix, or any other way to tell which line comes before which line.

Now, suppose that Filebeat reads the log file every second. During that second, 3 log lines were written. Filebeat does not know their timing, so **it gives all three the same timestamp - their ingestion time, rather than their creation time**:

ES has no way to know which one comes first, hence the confusion on the reader side.

Will update when I have a Filebeat solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The solution is to put a timestamp in your logs so you can use it in logstash and ES doesn't have to guess.  Imagine if your network was down for a week and you were trying to replay logs...  Pretty messy.